# Reuters Eikon/Datastream - obtain issue date of structured products

Tags: date, derivative, reuters, thomson-reuters-eikon

I want to download the isse date (or the date were the first price was set up) of 1,000 bonus certificates of different issuers.

To do so, I converted Wertpapierkennummern (WKN, identifier at German exchanges) into RICs. With those RICs I could download different data (e.g. Strike, Last Trading Date, Underlying RIC, Prices...) without any issues.

However, I need the issue date (or date were the first price was set up). This is stated on the "Overview" page of the certificates as "Isse Date". But the Data Item Browser () doesn't hold such a field.

In Datastream the field "ID" (Issue Date) returns solely "NA" values for all products.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

The need for the issue date is the following: I want to have a timeseries of prices which covers the life time of the derivative, so I have to cut down my used sample and want to sort the products out by using Date of first price (issue date) and the last trading date.

If there is a better solution please let me know!

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a RIC or ISIN you are looking at?

Comment: Hi Hoenie, I solved my issue by employing a webscraper which downloads the issue dates from an external website.

Comment: Gotcha. If the data is available is on the overview page, one would expect it to be available through APIs too. It is possible to do sort of a reverse lookup in the Data Item Browser, by filtering out empty rows and using CTR-F for search.

Comment: That's a great hint! Thank you. I will give it a try.